# python - printing items inline in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I need to print everything inline dynamically in a for loop in an IPython notebook. I am using **python 2.7**. I used the code:

```
for i in xrange(10):
   print "." , 
   #some computation and no print statement
```

and even used:

```
for i in xrange(10):
   print "\b."
   #some computation and no print statement
```

but both of the above solutions doesn't seem to work in IPython notebooks.

what I need is: `..........` and what the above snippets are printing is:

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Any and every help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to do a progressbar, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm that integrtes with the IPython notebook.

Answer (score 4):

This will work on both Python 2 and Python 3:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(10):
    print('.', end='')
```

You can also pass `flush=True` keyword argument to force it to flush the buffer instantly.

You can also overwrite a previous line using `'\r'`, her's a simple example:

```py
import time

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('\r{} / 10'.format(i + 1, 10), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in xrange(10):
   print(".", end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sys` module.

```
import sys

for i in xrange(10):
    sys.stdout.write(".")
```

The `print` function  is a wrapper which converts the object to `string` and formats the output.

Answer (score -2):

I may not understand your question but have you tried to use:

```
print "."*10
```

You would get:

```
..........
```

Comment: As the OP specified there is some computation after each print statement. He doesn't just want to print a line of points all at once.